# can same physical address be allocated to different virtual address in different processes?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

In Linux with 4KB page size, we have two processes A & B.
If process A allocated 1KB and process B allocated 1KB, is there any chance that kernel will map physical address X of size 4k, where first 1k byte of X to process A and 2nd 1k byte of X to process B ? or kernel will use different address Y  to either of these processes ?

Is this a valid scenario ?

Answer (score 2):

> is there any chance that kernel will map physical address X of size 4k, where first 1k byte of X to process A and 2nd 1k byte of X to process B ?

No. The page size is the smallest allocation size, so the kernel cannot allocate less than 4kB of memory. If a process requests less than that amount of memory, the kernel rounds it *up* to the nearest PAGE_SIZE in the case of both [mmap(2)](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/df0cc57e057f18e44dac8e6c18aba47ab53202f9/mm/mmap.c#L1436) and [brk(2)](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/df0cc57e057f18e44dac8e6c18aba47ab53202f9/mm/mmap.c#L235).

> or kernel will use different address Y to either of these processes ?

Each process will receive one separate physical page. They could have the same virtual address, but that doesn't matter since they're independent processes with their own page tables.

Comment: Thanks @Sagar, but linux slub will create smaller chunks of memory within 4k to reduce internal fragmentation and service smaller memory requests, in that case also the above scenario will not arise ?

Comment: @valmiki: slub allocates kernel memory, in the **kernel address space**. This memory doesn't belong to specific process. Instead, all processes shares the same kernel address space. (And user space applications has no access to that address space.)

Comment: The allocator *dlmalloc*, *jemalloc*, etc will partition the memory in user space.  It is correct that only page size will be assigned.   But I think the confusion is that user space normally uses kernel allocation functions directly.  In fact it is cached by the standard libraries using either `mmap` or `sbrk`.  There is an extra level of detail that is being missed, the rounded up value goes to the *free store* so the next allocation won't even call the kernel.